# Labeling min/max stretch render

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, labeling, color-ramp

I have several rasters that show the percentage of sediment (mud,sand, gravel) at different locations.  I followed along with the ESRI "Advanced labeling for the stretch renderer" guide but I am encountering a problem where my new labels are being overridden by the default labels.

I want a stretched raster that is comparable across all locations so I am using the Stretch Type "Minimum-Maximum" to change the values to be 0 - 100.  I would like my legend to be labeled at 0, 25, 50, 75 and 100. I used the advanced labeling to set the interval size to 25.  For a second the labels show correctly as I have indicated but after another second they revert back to High : 100 and Low : 0 without any additional labels between. See the screen shots below. What can I do to avoid my labels reverting to the default values?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you change anything in the Layer Properties Symbology *after* setting your label options?

Comment: No, the labels change as soon as I hit OK/apply. The new labels appear for a second and then are replaced by the default.  The only way I was able to capture the screen shot was because I was waiting for it.  It seems like there is a setting that is overriding my new labels.

Comment: I can confirm that I get the same issue with 10.3.1 (but it works fine in 10.5).  For me it changed almost instantly - ie I saw it flash in the TOC but never actually saw the correct values other than a slight blur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug, according to a thread on Geonet - [Advanced Labeling for stretched renderer with Hi/Low values](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/110053):

> There is a bug report, **NIM67106**, that is currently assigned to a
>   developer for this behavior.  If you would like to be added to the
>   incident then please log a Support Incident, as always the more users
>   on the bug report, the more visibility it has for development to
>   consider it to be fixed.

According to the [ArcGIS 10.5 Issues Addressed list](http://downloads.esri.com/support/downloads/other_/105-IssuesAddressedList_12082016.pdf) the bug was fixed in this release (which is why it worked for me in 10.5).

> **NIM067106** - Labels on a graduated color ramp do not appear when rendering a raster
>   using minimum-maximum and the 'edit low/high values' option is
>   selected.

Here is the Nimbus page on Esri Support

[Bug NIM067106](http://support.esri.com/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDY3MTA2) and also [Bug BUG-000087313](http://support.esri.com/bugs/nimbus/QlVHLTAwMDA4NzMxMw==)